# $x_n \to 0$ weakly $\iff$ $Tx_n \to 0$ for all $T$ in $X^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I'm trying to understand this passage from Rudin's Functional Analysis:

> Since every weak neighborhoud of $0$ contains a neighborhood of the
>   form $V = \{x: |T_ix| < r_i, 1 \le i \le n\}$ where $T_i \in X^*$ and
>   $r_i>0$ ...

Does this mean that for every weak neighborhoud $U$ of $0$ there exists $T_1 \ldots, T_n \in X^*$ and $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ positive such that $U \supset \{x: |T_ix| < r_i, 1 \le i \le n\} $?

He goes on...

> This implies that $x_n \to 0$ weakly $\iff$ $Tx_n \to 0$ for all $T$
>   in $X^*$.

How does this follow?

Comment: Regarding your first question: yes, it means exactly that. As for the second question: the first observation does not imply the equivalence you wrote, only the implication $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: (Everytime you talk about a book, be explicit about what book you are talking about. You seem to think that Rudin wrote only one book.)

Comment: $\implies$ direction follows by continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, yes you interpreted it correctly.  For the second, suppose $x_n\to 0$ weakly and $T\in X^*$.  Given $\varepsilon>0$, the set $U=\{x\in X:|Tx|<\varepsilon\}$ is a weak open neighborhood of $0$, hence there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_n\in U$ for all $n\geq N$.  In other words, $|Tx_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.  Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have $Tx_n\to 0$.

For the reverse direction, let $U$ be a weak open neighborhood of $0$.  Then there exist $T_1,\ldots,T_m\in X^*$ and $r_1,\ldots,r_m>0$ such that $\{x: |T_ix| < r_i, 1 \le i \le m\}\subset U$.  For $1\leq i\leq m$. there is some $N_i\in\mathbb N$ such that $|T_ix_n|<r_i$ for $n\geq N_i$.  Let $N=\max\{N_i:1\leq i\leq m\}$.  Then $|T_ix_n|<_i$ for all $i$ whenever $n\geq N$.  That is, $x_n\in U$ for all $n\geq N$.  Since the neighborhood $U$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $x_n\to0$ weakly.

Comment: Why is it the case that every weak neighborhoud of $0$ contains such a $V$?

Comment: @theQman, there is no $V$ in this answer.

Comment: I mean, why do such $T_1, \ldots, T_m$ and $r_1, \ldots, r_m$ exist?

Comment: @theQman It comes from the definition of the weak topology.  The collection of all such sets forms a neighborhood basis at $0$

Comment: @Aweygan The definition of the weak topology here is: it is the weakest topology on $X$ such that all of the linear maps in $X^*$ (the continuous linear functionals from $X$ to $\mathbf{C}$ or $\mathbf{R}$) are still continuous. So in this case, $\{x:|Tx|<r\} = T^{-1}((-r, r))$  is open in weak topology on $X$? Is this more or less the reasoning that is going on here? And $\{x:|T_ix|<r_i, 1 \le i \le n\}$ is an intersection of these types of open sets?

Comment: @theQman Yes, the weakest topology such that elements of $X^*$ are continuous has as a subbasis the collection of sets of the form $T^{-1}(U)$, where $T\in X^*$ and $U\subset\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) is open.

Comment: @Aweygan but then why the claim that there exists $T_1, \ldots, T_m \in X^*$? Isn't it true for all $T \in X^*$?

Comment: @theQman No.  You need to take intersections of subbasis elements to obtain a basis for the topology.

Comment: @Aweygan More precisely, I mean isn't it true that for every $T \in X^*$, and every weak neighborhood $U$ of $0$ , there exists $r>0$ such that $U$ contains a neighborhood of the form $\{x: |Tx|<r\}$? I am still missing some main point here... does local convexity come in to play at all?

Comment: @theQman That is not true.  If you have a general weak open neighborhood $U$, and some $T\in X^*$, in general we do not have $\{x: |Tx|<r\}\subset U$ for some $r>0$.  Consider this: if $T,S\in X^*$ have different kernels, then $\{x: |Tx|<r_1\}$ and $\{x: |Sx|<r_2\}$ are both weak open neighborhoods of $0$, but neither will contain the other.

Comment: @Aweygan I see. And this isn't really specific to the weak topology, is it? If $U$ is open (wrt some topology) and contains 0, then there exists continuous linear functionals (wrt that same topology) $T_1, \ldots, T_m$, and $r_1, \ldots, r_m$, such that, etc... ?

Comment: @theQman It is specific to this topology.  An open ball in a norm topology is bounded, but a set of the form $\{x: |T_ix-T_ix_0| < r_i, 1 \le i \le n\}$ always contains some infinite-dimensional hyperplane (some shift of the intersection of the kernels of the $T_i$), which is not bounded.

Comment: @Aweygan Ah, I think I see now. It all comes back to the weak topology being *defined* by the subbasis elements $T^{-1}(U)$ with $T \in X^*$, $U$ open in whatever the scalar field is. Thanks!

Comment: @theQman Exactly, and you're welcome.  Glad to help!